# Visual Studio and KVM version mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, kvm, asp.net-core-mvc, kruntime

Everything was working fine until I performed kvm upgrade on the console.

It seems that Visual Studio is working from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools
```

and KVM is working from

```
c:\users\username\.k
```

It seems as though Visual Studio provided the K runtime without KVM. Because there is no KVM script in "Microsoft Web Tools" folder, but there is one in "username.k\bin".

So far I've tried setting the default alias, and using kvm in the visual studio console. [Asp Forms has a thread, but no answers](http://forums.asp.net/t/2037600.aspx?Getting%20the%20latest%20KRE%20to%20work%20with%20visual%20studio%202015)

Why the version difference between KVM and Visual Studio? How do I use a newer version of KRE with visual studio?

[image: KVM Versions list in Visual Studio]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the VS 2015 CTP <= 5. If you install the latest [VS 2015 CTP 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/23/visual-studio-2015-ctp-6-and-team-foundation-server-2015-ctp-released.aspx), you should see that VS and KVM look in the same place for KRE's:

[image]